# extra data series in plot from sm.density.compare function in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm using the sm.density.compare function in the R sm package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sm/index.html). The plot produces 3 density functions despite the fact that my data contained only two groups, when (and only when) I include the test of equal densities.  My question is: **What is the third density plot series?**  Is it a limit of significance from one of the plots?  I can't find a description for the third series in any documentation.

Specifically:

Pvalue <- sm.density.compare(DataVector,GroupVector,model="none")

and

Pvalue <- sm.density.compare(DataVector,GroupVector,model="equal")

produce plots of 2 and 3 series, respectively.  There are only 2 groups, respectively identified in the GroupVector as 0 and 0.3.

I tried to post the plots but apparently my reputation is not yet high enough to post images.

Comment: We don't want images. We want str(on the data).

Comment: Looking at the example on the help page, which you could have easiy cited, it appears there is a band representing the common density CI.